# Why factorial calculation with ForkJoin framework slower that sequential calculation with recursion

Tags: java, factorial, fork-join, forkjoinpool

I implemented factorial calculation in two ways - using recursion and using ForkJoin framework. I was expecting that ForkJoin implementation will be faster, but in all cases that I tried to test it was always slower (I tried to calculate factorial for different numbers and also tried to tune the parallelism level). Here are both my implementations - without FJ:

```
public class SequentialFactorial {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(calculateFactorial(BigInteger.valueOf(500)));
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println((end - start) + " nanoseconds for sequential");
    }

    private static BigInteger calculateFactorial(BigInteger n) {
        if (n.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(2)) <= 0) {
            return n;
        }

        return n.multiply(calculateFactorial(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
    }
}
```

And with it:

```
public class ForkJoinFactorial {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(forkJoinPool.invoke(new FactorialTask(BigInteger.valueOf(500))));
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println((end - start) + " nanoseconds for FJP");
    }
}

public class FactorialTask extends RecursiveTask<BigInteger> {
    private BigInteger number;

    public FactorialTask(BigInteger number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    protected BigInteger compute() {
        if (number.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(1)) <= 0) {
            return MathUtil.calculateFactorial(number);
        }
        FactorialTask subtask = new FactorialTask(number.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
        subtask.fork();
        return number.multiply(subtask.join());
    }
}
```

In my last tests I got such results:

> 5424981 nanoseconds for sequential
>
> 11874865 nanoseconds for FJP

Why my FJ implementation is slower and how can I improve that?

Comment: You join right after you fork. You get all the overhead of setting up the task and 0 parallelism.

Comment: Fork-join is only efficient if you can break the main task into several small sub-tasks. Since your recursion is dependent on the completion of the whole (single) subtask, you are not actually parallelizing anything here.

Comment: As for improving it, I don't know if this would really make things faster (over a sequential loop), but if you want to split tasks evenly for two CPU, you could multiply up all the even numbers in one task and all the odds in the other (or use `mod N` for more partitions). Your `FactorialTask` would need an extra parameter to select the partition.